# resample and normalize a numpy array for gesture recognition

Tags: python, numpy, resize, normalization, gesture-recognition

i'm going to write a little application to recognize gesture (for now with the mouse).

now, record the mouse coordinate in a numpy array of Point object (simple class with x and y attributes).
for training my system (based on HMM) i need (i think...) some sample of the same lenght normalized beetween the same range.

Say, for example, that i need an array of 8 element length for my training and for my classifier.
And i have just recordered a1( 5-len element ), and a2( 9-len element ). How to achive len(a1)==len(a2)==8 ?

**EDIT**: i found a website that explain my problem:
http://www.creativedistraction.com/demos/gesture-recognition-kinect-with-hidden-markov-models-hmms/
he uses k-means for reduce element in 8 cluster..

**SOLUTION**: i have some scattered points (i don't know how many) and i want to reduce it to a 8 meaning point. one of the technique i can use is to clusterize them with some cluster algorithms. KMeans could be one possibility. in scipy with this code:
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2

```
def clusterize(numpy_array, n_cluster):
    centroids, labels = kmeans2(numpy_array, n_cluster)
    #print centroids, labels
    return centroids
```

note: if numpy_array size is less then n_cluster i noticed that the solutions are not good, but in my real case after some trials i observed that i have more than (numpy_array size>=60, n_cluster=8). this is quite logical: k-means is not a deterministic alorightm but it is a iterative process that involved some random initialization, because there are no analitical good solution for this kind of problem (if i understood well).

for sure there are some mathematical insight that i don't want to delve into. this do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need, but this will linearly interpolate from the input along `n` evenly spaced points.

```
input = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) ** 2
n = 8
m = len(input)
out = np.interp(np.linspace(0, m-1, n), np.arange(m), input)
```